# How to convert list into row using pandas if the name and there value is stored in one list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

```
                                          Analyte_line
0                                                  NaN
1    [['Urea', 3.0, '3', ''], ['Creatinine', 3.0, '...
2    [['Total Protein', '', '6', ''], ['Albumin', '...
3    [['HGB', '', '18', ''], ['RBC', '', '1', ''], ...
4    [['Total Protein', '', '23', ''], ['Albumin', ...
..                                                 ...
102            [['Rapid Malaria', '', 'NEGATIVE', '']]
103  [['Rapid Malaria', '', 'POSITIVE (P.VIVAX)', '']]
104            [['Rapid Malaria', '', 'NEGATIVE', '']]
105  [['Rapid Malaria', '', 'POSITIVE (P.VIVAX)', '']]
106            [['Rapid Malaria', '', 'NEGATIVE', '']]

this given data is stored in a data frame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

In data each name and value is stored  list. How can we convert this data frame in row and columns wise like

| Urea | Creatinine | Uric Acid | Alkaline Phosphatase | Test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3.0 , 3 | 3.0 , 3 | 3.0 , 3 | 4 | Positive |

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns =['Urea', 'Creatinine', 'Uric Acid', 'Alkaline Phosphatase', 'Test']
print(df)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = (df
 .set_index(0).T.astype(str)
 .agg(lambda s: ','.join(x for x in s if x))
 .to_frame().T
)
```

Or:

```
out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0: {k: ','.join(x for x in map(str, l) if x)
                                  for k, *l in data}}, orient='index')
```

Output:

```
    Urea Creatinine Uric Acid Alkaline Phosphatase      Test
0  3.0,3      3.0,3     3.0,3                    4  Positive
```

Comment: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "[['Urea', 3.0, '3', ''], ['Creatinine', 3.0, '3', ''], ['Uric Acid', 3.0, '3', '']]"

Comment: Do you have a list or a string representation of a list? Convert with `data = ast.literal_eval(data)`

Comment: both list and string representation.

Comment: @Muhammad well your question is unclear, please stick to the reproducible object that you provided in the question. If you have a different one, update the question. In any case you can't expect the answer to work with a completely different object than the one that is provided.

Comment: I think due to Analyte_line it give error.

Comment: Your update is not valid python, please ensure to provide a reproducible object. It should run with no error in a clean python interpreter.

Comment: I'm sorry @Muhammad but not in a reproducible way, please provide the output of `df.head().to_dict('list')`